# bash script to create folder from filename and move two kinds of file into it

Tags: bash

I have a set of banners that include .jpg and .psd. I need to create folder for them and move them into it.

```
example:
Banner-A.jpg
Banner-A.psd
Banner-B.jpg
Banner-B.psd
Banner-C.jpg
Banner-C.psd

Create folder and move them: 
Banner-A/Banner-A.jpg Banner-A.psd
Banner-B/Banner-B.jpg Banner-B.psd
Banner-C/Banner-C.jpg Banner-C.psd
```

I manage to find a script here that work for the first part but I can't get the .psd to move as well.

```
for f in "$@"; do
    cd "$f"
    for file in *.jpg; do
       folder=$(basename "$file" ".jpg")
       mkdir -p "$folder" && mv "$file" "$folder"
    done
done
```

Comment: `for file in *.jpg` will only iterate over the `jpg` but not the `psd`.

Comment: @Don : I don't see where in your script you would move files ending in '.psd'. Since you know how you move jpg-files, where is the difficulty of doing the same with files ending in a different three-letter-sequence?

Comment: If you always have one psd file for each jpg file with the same basename, just add a `mv "$folder.psd" "$folder"` at the end of the inner loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `mv` command to use the `*` wildcard as follows:

```
for file in *.jpg; do
    folder=$(basename "$file" ".jpg")
    mkdir -p "${folder}" && mv "${folder}".* "${folder}"
done
```

Make sure the `.*` is outside the quotes and it should work.

Example script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -uo pipefail

doWork() {
    dir="${1}"
    cd "${dir}" || return
    for file in *.jpg; do
       folder=$(basename "$file" ".jpg")
       mkdir -p "${folder}" && mv "${folder}".* "${folder}"
    done
}

doWork "$@"
```

Example data directory: (before executing script)

```
$ ls data
Banner-A.jpg Banner-A.psd Banner-B.jpg Banner-B.psd Banner-C.jpg Banner-C.psd
```

Run script:

```
./script.sh ./data
```

data directory after script:

```
$ ls data
Banner-A Banner-B Banner-C
```

data directory subdirectories:

```
$ ls data/Banner-*
data/Banner-A:
Banner-A.jpg Banner-A.psd

data/Banner-B:
Banner-B.jpg Banner-B.psd

data/Banner-C:
Banner-C.jpg Banner-C.psd
```

Comment: `set -e` is, by the way, by no means considered good practice. See [BashFAQ #105](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Examples) for some exercises describing how it often hurts predictability and comprehensibility more than it helps, and https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/ demonstrating how its behavior is wildly unportable across different shells (as well as across different releases of the same shell).

Comment: Also, `function doWork() {` combines the legacy ksh syntax `function doWork {` and the POSIX-standardized syntax `doWork() {` in a manner that's compatible with neither legacy ksh nor POSIX. See https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete, including entries in both the first and third tables.

Comment: (Thus, I'd suggest `cd "$dir" || return` to abort the function if the `cd` fails; certainly agreed you don't want to just ditch `set -e` and have no handling for the case).

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy I updated my answer per your comments and will have a look at the links you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably just use

```
for f in Banner*.jpg Banner*.psd; do
  mkdir -p "${f%.???}/"
  mv "$f" "${f%.???}/"
done
```

It will execute the `mkdir -p` for the `*.psg` files after the `*.jpg` has already created the folder, but covers the odd cases where there might be one of the files but not the other.